# Prove this function is strictly convex

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I need to understand how to prove a function of this form is strictly convex:

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by:

$f(x) = 2x_1^2 + 3x_2^2 + x_3^2$.

Prove by using the definition,  i.e. $f(\lambda + (1-\lambda)b) < \lambda f(a) + (1-\lambda)f(b)$, that $f$ is strictly convex.

Thank you in advance for any answer that might help explaining the procedure

Comment: Just recognise that $$(x+t)^2>x^2 \space \forall t>0$$ and apply the relevant definitions

Comment: I`m sorry I still get it, could you maybe show me where would you use this inequality?

Comment: The definition of strong convexity is *not* what you described. Strong convexity is the other way around, i.e.

$$
f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) < \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(y), \; \lambda \in (0, 1).
$$

Comment: You`re right, I edited!

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a solution, the problem can be solved by using $2xy < x^2 + y^2$, because x is not equal to y.